# Is this normal to have big value of Chi Squared?

Tags: chi-squared-test, feature-selection

I am using chi squared for feature selection in text classification.

However when I compute it I sometime have very big values. Like 100, 1000 or even 20000.

Is this normal ?

I wonder because I read that if the Chi Squared score equals 10.83 then the p-value is 0.01.

So we know at 99.99% that the token and the class of a text document are dependant.

What do this mean for 20000 ? Are we sure at 99.9999999 % or something like that ?

---

**---- EDIT 6/23/2014 ---**

---

Here is more information about what I am trying to do with chi-square.

We have 64893 documents.
For each document we tell if it belongs to a category (in this case we write a +1 next to it) or if it does not belong to it (in which case we write a -1 next to it).

For each word in the corpus of document, we want to determine if it is a word which is helpful to put the document in the category.

The NULL hypothesis is "document category has no influence over word frequency".

The degree of freedom is 1.

Here are a few example of the big results I receive:

The first one have a Chi-Score of 32250

[image]

---

The second one have a Chi-Score of 11410

[image]

**---- EDIT 6/24/2014 ---**

Imagine I have the following documents:

```
I am very happy 
I was happy yesterday
I am kind of sad
I am happy today
I am sad
they are happy now
yesterday, he was not happy
today he is happy
they will be happy tomorrow
```

For each document, we manually identify documents talking about someone happy **right now**
by giving them the class +1

```
+1   I am very happy 
-1   I was happy yesterday
-1   I am kind of sad
+1   I am happy today
-1   I am sad 
+1   they are happy now
-1   yesterday, he was not happy
+1   today he is happy
-1   they will be happy tomorrow
+1   happy day today ! I am happy
```

For each document, we gather the statistics for each word like in the example below. *(Here I am not sure If I should put a 2 for the "happy" word because it appears twice or just a 1 because it appears)*

```
//  happy day today ! I am happy

category = "+1", 

happy                  1
sad                    0
today                  1
kind                   0
of                     1
not                    0
will                   0
be                     1
tomorrow               0
very                   0
are                    0
now                    0
is                     0
day                    1
I                      1
was                    0
yesterday              0
they                   0
he                     0
am                     1
```

Now we want to determine for each word, how much they help to determine if a document belongs to the class. We compute the Chi-Square score for each word:

```
happy                               3.75
sad                                 3.75
today                   2.85714285714286
kind                    1.66666666666667
of                      1.66666666666667
not                     1.66666666666667
will                    1.66666666666667
be                      1.66666666666667
tomorrow                1.66666666666667
very                   0.740740740740741
are                    0.740740740740741
now                    0.740740740740741
is                     0.740740740740741
day                    0.740740740740741
I                      0.277777777777778
was                    0.104166666666667
yesterday              0.104166666666667
they                   0.104166666666667
he                     0.104166666666667
am                                     0
```

*If I put a "2" instead of a "1" for the happy word in the document "happy day today! I am happy" I obtain*

```
happy                   11.8518518518519
sad                                 3.75
today                   2.85714285714286
kind                    1.66666666666667
of                      1.66666666666667
.
.
.
```

Comment: There is no reason why you can't have a very large chi squared test statistic if the expectations vary a lot between groups and you have a large sample for each group. In such a case you are nearly certain that the differences between the groups didn't happen by chance.

Comment: "*because I read that if the Chi Squared score equals 10.83 then the p-value is 0.01.*" -- this would be an upper bound on the p-value at some particular degrees of freedom, like $\nu=2$. The expected value of a chi-square will be a combination of your d.f., and how false your null hypothesis is (and potentially some other things). If your d.f. is large, you can get a large chi-square even if the null is true.

Comment: Did you check the 0-1 normalized version (Cramér's V)?

Comment: Two questions come to mind: (a) what sample sizes are you using? and (b) are all your observations independent (as assumed by chi sq)?  Very large sample sizes can yield large chi sq values and non-independent observations can also.  The former is legitimate, the latter is not.

Comment: @Glen_b I did not understand the degree of freedom, I will try to compute it with my dataset to check if I am using the upper bound correctly

Comment: @MichaelMayer I will take a look at it

Comment: @JoelW. (a) I am using a dataset of 67587 documents (b) The document have been classified manually, each one received the "+1" class if it belong to the class or the "-1" class if it does not. I think this mean they are independent observation has each document has been classified individually –

Comment: The large sample size (67,000+) can contribute to large chi-sq values but, even so, your values are very high.  Are the rates very different between groups?  How many degrees of freedom do you have for your chi-sq tests? Also, why are you doing multiple chi-sq tests?  Are they testing similar effects?

Comment: @JoelW. I edited the post to add more explanations

Comment: The additional detail helps, but I am still not clear enough on the procedure to be sure that the data collected are independent (as they should be) or are not independent (which might account for your large values of chi-sq).  Perhaps it would help if you gave a (simplified) example of a document and a few words that would be categorized as +1 or -1?

Comment: @JoelW.  I added a more detailed example. Thanks for your help

Comment: (1) You have huge chi-sq values because you have a huge effect. (A document about happiness will be much more likely to contain the word happy than a document not about happiness.)  (2) you are doing multiple tests, so your alpha is inflated.  But that does not account for your very high chi-sq values.  (3) In your example, coding happy as 1 seems to be more appropriate than coding it as 2, since the words in the sentence are not independent.  (4) I could not replicate some of your chi sq values, so one of us must be calculating something incorrectly.  (Are you using a continuity correction?)

Comment: @JoelW. (2) What do you mean by "your alpha is inflated"? 
(4) Which value could you not replicate?  I am using the formula of equation [4] from this article: http://blog.datumbox.com/using-feature-selection-methods-in-text-classification/